# how to integrate facebook in my application in iphone

Tags: iphone, objective-c

i am creating a music application and i want to integrate facebook into my application.when the user logs in for the first time in facebook the log in page of facebook should be displayed and after when he clicks on the login button my custom dialog page should be displayed containing buttons of publish feed, retrieving friends and logout and when the user clicks on a particluar button for.e.g publish feed his wall page should be displayed and when he enters some information in that it should be posted to his wall and  his friends wall and how can i create  the template bundle id of my application in facebook.

Please help me regarding this problem

Comment: What have you implemented so far?  What specific part are you having problems with?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See: http://wiki.developers.facebook.com/index.php/Facebook_iPhone_SDK.

Have you tried implementing any of the application above? People will generally be more helpful if you attempt the a solution and have specific problems.